# File class cannot access file using absolute path

Tags: java

I am trying to access a file using the file class but it works only with below code

```
File file = new File("s:\\testing\\selenium\\Version8\\locators\\OR.properties");
```

however I need to use this approach where I go directly to the server:
`"\\GIGABYTE\\s-drive\\Testing\\selenium\\Version8\\locators\OR.properties"`in which the above will not find the file - very strange

Any clue as to why this is?

Comment: It certainly doesn't work with your first piece of code since the argument is not a valid Java string. As to your second version, not sure whether `File` understands UNC paths. Maybe try with the more modern `Path` instead?

Answer (score 1):

To go directly to the server you will need to have 4 slashes as two are actual slashes and 2 are escape characters:

```
\\\\GIGABYTE\\s-drive\\Testing\\selenium\\Version8\\locators\OR.properties
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code:

```
File file = new File("\\\\GIGABYTE\\s-drive\\Testing\\selenium\\Version8\\locators\\OR.properties");
```

or this:

```
File file = new File("//GIGABYTE/s-drive/Testing/selenium/Version8/locators/OR.properties");
```